I am getting an error when trying to create a Markov Chain
I am writing a Markov Chain that predicts the next word based on a small section of preceding words.
I have this chunk of code to add words to the model however, when I run the program, I am getting this error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'"
def add(self,word):
    """post: Adds word as a possible following word for current state of the
    Markov Model and sets state to incorporate word as most recently seen.

    ex: If state was ('the','man') and the word is 'ate', the 'ate' is added
    as a word that can follow '... the man' and the state is now ('man', 'ate')"""

    if self.state in self.model: #If we have an existing list of words for this state
        self.model[self.state].append(word) # Just add this new word
    else: # First occurance of this state
        self.model[self.state] = [word] #create a new list

    self._transition(word) #Transition to the next state given the next word`

I am using a dictionary to map states into a new words (self.model) and a tuple to represent the last two words processed (self.state)
please help

Do any other methods attempt to set entries in self.model?  Assuming the problem append call is coming from this method, the error implies that self.model[self.state] is a string, so would have to have come from elsewhere.

The code example provided is not sufficient to understand or reproduce the problem. As @TomKarzes mentioned, the self.model[self.state] appears to hold a string, but it gets initialized as a list (self.model[self.state] = [word]), so it must be re-assigned in some other part of the code. Do you assign to the self.model variable somewhere else?

Does this answer your question? How to fix "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'"

This would be a good place to use a defaultdict().
